# While Loop with time.sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x

i will use a while loop for a refresh for a method.

```
def usagePerUserApi():
    while True:
        url = ....
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        data = json.loads(resp.content)
        code = resp.status_code
        Verbindungscheck.ausgabeVerbindungsCode(code)

        head =.....

        table = []
        for item in (data['data']):
            if item['un'] == tecNo:
                table.append([
                    item['fud'],
                    item['un'],
                    str(item['lsn']),
                    str(item['fns']),
                    str(item['musage'])+"%",
                    str(item['hu']),
                    str(item['mu']),
                    str(item['hb']),
                    str(item['mb'])
                ])
        print(tabulate(table,headers=head, tablefmt="github"))
        time.sleep(300)
```

If I leave time.sleep like this, it will be displayed as an error. If I put it under the while loop, It will be updated constantly and does not wait 5 minutes.

I don't know where the mistake is. I hope you can help me.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: NameError: name 'time' is not defined

Comment: Please, as you seem to be new on StackOverFlow, have a look at [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Then, you can **upvote** or **downvote** answer and **accept** an awser when this one solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the python time library

If you place

```py
import time
```

at the top of your file it should work

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported the `time` library? If not, then add

```py
import time
```

to the top of your code, and it should work.

Also bear in mind that there may be problems with output buffering, where the program won't wait as expected, and so you'll need to turn it off, as shown by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering).

Comment: It worked with import time, have forgot it . Thank you very much

Comment: @FabianBreuer no worries :))